# Reacjs recursive function

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a function and, depending on the case, I wish to recall the same function

```
 buildRoute(listRoutes){
    return(
      <Switch>
        {listRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
          if(prop.subMenus != null){
            if(prop.path !== undefined){
              return
                this.routes(prop, key);
                this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus);
            }else{
              return this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus);
            }
          }else{
            return this.routes(prop, key);
          }
        })}
      </Switch>
    )
  }

  routes(prop, key){
    if (prop.redirect){  
      return <Redirect from={prop.path} to={prop.to} key={key} />;
    }else if(prop.private){        
      return <PrivateRoute authenticated={JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(IS_AUTHENTICATED))} path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
    }else{
      return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} />;
    }
  }
```

But I have this error :
VM3056 53.chunk.js:89036 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `APP`.
    in Switch (at Dashboard.jsx:84)
    in APP (created by WithStyles(APP))
    in WithStyles(APP) (created by Route)
    in Route (at src/index.js:46)
    in Switch (at src/index.js:42)
    in Router (at src/index.js:41)
    in I18nextProvider (at src/index.js:40)

My listRoute :

```
        const dashboardRoutes = [
      {
        private: true,
        path: "/private/dashboard",
        sidebarName: "menu.sidebarName.dashboard",
        navbarName: "header.navbarName.dashboard",
        icon: Dashboard,
        component: DashboardPage
      },
      {
        private: true,
        path: "/private/MENU1",
        navbarName: "header.navbarName.MENU1",
        component: MENU1,
        sidebarName: "menu.sidebarName.MENU1",
        code: "MENU1",
        icon: "content_paste",
        subMenus:[
          {
        subMenu: true,
        private: true,
        path: "/private/MENU1_SOUS_MENU1",
        sidebarName: "menu.sidebarName.MENU1_SOUS_MENU1",
        navbarName: "header.navbarName.MENU1_SOUS_MENU1",
        code: "MENU1_SOUS_MENU1",
        icon: "content_paste",
        component: MENU1_SOUS_MENU1
      },
      {
        subMenu: true,
        private: true,
        path: "/private/MENU1_SOUS_MENU2",
        sidebarName: "menu.sidebarName.MENU1_SOUS_MENU2",
        navbarName: "header.navbarName.MENU1_SOUS_MENU2",
        code: "MENU1_SOUS_MENU2",
        icon: "content_paste",
        component: MENU1_SOUS_MENU2
      }
    ]
   },
   {
        sidebarName: "menu.sidebarName.MENU12",
        code: "MENU12,
        icon: "content_paste",
        subMenus:[
          {
        subMenu: true,
        private: true,
        path: "/private/MENU2_SOUS_MENU1",
        sidebarName: "menu.sidebarName.MENU2_SOUS_MENU1",
        navbarName: "header.navbarName.MENU2_SOUS_MENU1",
        code: "MENU2_SOUS_MENU1",
        icon: "content_paste",
        component: MENU2_SOUS_MENU1
      },
      {
        subMenu: true,
        private: true,
        path: "/private/MENU2_SOUS_MENU2",
        sidebarName: "menu.sidebarName.MENU2_SOUS_MENU2",
        navbarName: "header.navbarName.MENU2_SOUS_MENU2",
        code: "MENU2_SOUS_MENU2",
        icon: "content_paste",
        component: MENU2_SOUS_MENU2
      }
    ]
  },
   .....
  { 
    redirect: true, 
    path: "/private", 
    to: "/private/dashboard"
  }
  ]
```

Comment: the jsx of those functions you are calling need a unique `key` prop https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I saw this link but I didn’t find the solution to my problem

Comment: can you provide a sample `listRoutes` contents passed to `buildRoute` ?

Comment: also `return
                this.routes(prop, key);
                this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus);` this will only return the `this.routes(prop, key);`

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `buildRoute` can either return a `Route` or another `Switch`. Your `Switch` components do not have a key, though.

Also you have

```
if(prop.path !== undefined){
          return
            this.routes(prop, key);
            this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus);
        }
```

this will actually return nothing. And even if you move `this.routes` in the same line with `return` it will only return that and the `this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus);` will never be called. You should return an array with both elements in it.

All fixes together (*notice i am changing the signature of the `buildRoute` to accept an additional parameter*)

```js
buildRoute(listRoutes) {
    return (
        {listRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
          if (prop.subMenus != null) {
            if (prop.path !== undefined) {
              return [
                this.routes(prop, key),
                this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus)
              ];
            } else {
              return this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus);
            }
          } else {
            return this.routes(prop, key);
          }
        })}
    );
  }
  
render(){
  return <Switch>{this.buildRoute(dashboardRoutes)}</Switch>;
}
```

---

On further notice, you cannot have nested `Switch` elements (*see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6199*).

So remove the nesting`Switch` and wrap the results of `buildRoute` on a single `Switch`

Demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/ppwk4qnrox

Comment: I have updated my listRoute  with the all possibilities.

Comment: @dna i had accidentally removed a `, key` from one of the `this.routes(..)`. Updated answer

Comment: It is the same result

Comment: @dna what result is that ? You get the error about ***Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop*** ?

Comment: I have the same error : Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. The problem is most likely MENU2 with no path

Comment: @dna i have added some more info at the end and also updated the code. Also added a working demo to show that it works fine. Perhaps the problem is with one of the rendered components and not with the routes.

Comment: Thank you. That works. I think the problem was the Switch that was recreated every time they went through the process.

Comment: I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

That error is just because you haven't specified a key when you map through you listRoutes. You're not showing the this.routes method in your code here. But I guess it's there your're returning your JSX element. So you should set a key in there. You're already passing in the key so just use that one if you don't have a better choice.

Comment: What is the solution ?

Comment: @dna The second part of this answer is the solution: “*So you should set a key in there. You're already passing in the key so just use that one if you don't have a better choice.*”

Comment: When I call my function buildRoute(), I don't have a key

Comment: Youre not returning any JSX in your buildRoute. But in routes your'e returning JSX elements. So you can use the key your'e passing in to that method and set the key in your components your'e returning.

Comment: When I call buildRoute for the first time, what are parameters to pass?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone element so you can actually pass it a key. Passing down the key to child function doesn't works AFAIK.

```
buildRoute (listRoutes) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {listRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        if (prop.subMenus != null) {
          if (prop.path != null) {
            return React.cloneElement([
              this.routes(prop),
              this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus)
            ], { key });
          } else {
            return React.cloneElement(this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus), { key })
          }
        } else {
          return React.cloneElement(this.routes(prop), { key });
        }
      })}
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Then you can remove the `key` argument from `routes` function. Also remove `key={key}` in the `return`'s.

Another solution can be to wrap everything into a "wrapper" whose set the key.

```
buildRouteItem (prop) {
  if (prop.subMenus != null) {
    if (prop.path != null) {
      return [
        this.routes(prop),
        this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus)
      ]
    } else {
      return this.buildRoute(prop.subMenus);
    }
  } else {
    return this.routes(prop);
  }
}

buildRoute (listRoutes) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {listRoutes.map((prop, key) => (
        <div key={key}>
          {this.buildRouteItem(prop)}
        </div>
      ))}
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

Comment: Route redirect /private to /private/dashboard not working.

Comment: I have updated my listRoute  with the all possibilities.